# Dynamically set Func<> types

Tags: c#, types, func

is there any way to set `Func<>` type arguments dynamically, so i don't have to use endless `if` statements?

Something like:

```
Type t = Type.GetType("System.Decimal");
Func<t> foo = new Func<t>(some_function);
```

Instead of:

```
Func<Decimal> foo = new Func<Decimal>(some_function);
```

UPDATE:

Here's a snippet from my code:

```
Type t = typeof(StavkaDokumenta).GetProperty(pd.Polje).PropertyType;
ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(StavkaDokumenta), "stavka");
Expression expr = Expressions.ResolveCompleteExpression(pe, pd.Expression);
Expression final = Expression.Convert(expr, t);
if (t == typeof(decimal))
{
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<StavkaDokumenta, decimal>>(final, pe);
    o = lambda.Compile().Invoke(stavka);
}
if (t == typeof(decimal?))
{
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<StavkaDokumenta, decimal?>>(final, pe);
    o = lambda.Compile().Invoke(stavka);
}
else if (t == typeof(int))
{
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<StavkaDokumenta, int>>(final, pe);
    o = lambda.Compile().Invoke(stavka);
}
else if (t == typeof(int?))
{
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<StavkaDokumenta, int?>>(final, pe);
    o = lambda.Compile().Invoke(stavka);
}
else if (t == typeof(string))
{
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<string>>(final, null);
    o = lambda.Compile().Invoke();
}
```

pd.Polje is string - name of a property inside "StavkaDokumenta" class.
pd.Expression is string expression that must evaluate to type of Polje.
stavka is an instance of StavkaDokumenta.

Comment: If you are using endless ifs, maybe there is something about your current approach that could be improved? I would at least consider it.

Comment: Could you provide an example of an endless if chain that you're trying to resolve?

Comment: If you're using endless `xxx is SomeType`, there is probably something wrong with your design.

Comment: How does changing the type to a type variable involve if statements?

Comment: @BaliC: I think he is doing something along the lines of this: `if(t == typeof(decimal)) foo = new Func<decimal>(some_function); else if(t == typeof(string)) foo = new Func<string>(some_function);`

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, btw what type of `foo` in your last example?

Comment: That is just what i am doing Daniel

Comment: Can you please describe in one or two sentences what the snippet you just added to your question achieves? In other words, how would the lambda expression look like if this wouldn't be dynamic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Now that you showed what you really want, the answer is much more simple:
As you are apparently only interested in the return value of that expression, you could change your code to this:

```
Type t = typeof(StavkaDokumenta).GetProperty(pd.Polje).PropertyType;
ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(StavkaDokumenta), "stavka");
Expression expr = Expressions.ResolveCompleteExpression(pe, pd.Expression);
Expression final = Expression.Convert(expr, t);

if (t == typeof(string))
{
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<string>>(final, null);
    o = lambda.Compile().Invoke();
}
else
{
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(final, pe);
    o = lambda.Compile().DynamicInvoke(stavka);
}
```

---

Old answer:

You can use generics and implicit conversion to `Func<T>` to achieve this:

```
Func<T> GetFunc<T>(Func<T> func)
{
    return func;
}
```

Call it with a method group like so:

```
var foo = GetFunc(SomeMethod);
```

This assumes that `SomeMethod` looks like this:

```
decimal SomeMethod()
{
    // ...
}
```

`foo` will be of type `Func<decimal>`. If the return type of `SomeMethod` would be a `string`, the type of `foo` would be `Func<string>`.

---

What happens in this code is the following:

The parameter that is passed to `GetFunc` is a so-called "method group" and not a variable of type `Func<T>`. However, there exists an implicit conversion from a method group to a variable of `Func<T>`:

```
Func<decimal> func = SomeMethod; // an implicit conversion happens here
```

That implicit conversion is exactly what is happening here: Before `GetFunc` is even called, the method group `SomeMethod` is converted the a variable of type `Func<T>`. The concrete type used for `T` is additionally inferred by the compiler based on the return type of the method `SomeMethod()`.
Our goal was to create an instance of `Func<T>` based on our method group. And because that already happens in the conversion of the parameter before the method is even called, we simply return that created instance from the method.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't follow. Your method `GetFunc<T>` is effectively doing nothing. It returns the parameter as the same type it began.

Comment: @Yuck: The magic is happening in the call itself because there exists an implicit conversion from a method group (`SomeMethod`) to a variable of type `Func<T>`.

Comment: I'll try it now Daniel, but I think that will do the trick. I was stuck and was starting to settle with ifs...

Comment: @DanielHilgarth how it will help to avoid `if` checks? E.g. `if(t == typeof(decimal)) foo = GetFunc(decimal_function); else if(t == typeof(string)) foo = GetFunc(string_function);` and what type of foo should be in this example to compile?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: I don't understand the question. The code you copied from my comment doesn't compile in its form, it was meant as pseudo code.

Comment: @MilosMijatovic: You shouldn't answer your question, if you have another question. Instead, **update** your question please.

Comment: @MilosMijatovic: What type are `final` and `pe`? How are they initialized?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, thats exactly why I'm asking how your GetFunc method could be used. I just don't understand how it could help to remove endless `if` statements.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: To be honest, now that I think about it, I can't seem to find a case where it would be useful, except when using `dynamic`.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. That was it! Great!

Comment: Where is 'Expressions.ResolveCompleteExpression' method? I don't see it.

Comment: @CraigBoland: I assume it is a method the OP created.